# How can I gain resistance to poison and/or necrotic damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage-resistance, poison, resistance

I'm about to start a campaign that I suspect will be filled with poisonous & necrotic monsters due to the setting. I have been thinking of playing a stout halfling, but would prefer to play one with a wisdom bonus. Are there any other ways to gain resistance to at least one of these types?

I will likely be a squishy cleric in a caster role, so I should be able to avoid most of it - but I'm wondering if there's anything else I can do.

Comment: Do you accept magic items?

Answer (score 9):

## Backgrounds don't grant that kind of feature

Backgrounds grant two proficiencies (generally two skills and two of languages, tools, instruments, etc.) and a story/worldinteraction type feature, not something like a damage resistance.

## Feats

The feat Infernal Constitution (*Xanathar's* page 75) grants you resistance against poison damage (and advantage on saves against being poisoned). It does, however, require you to be a tiefling who don't get bonuses to wisdom.

## Races

All dwarves (PHB pages 18-20) get resistance to poison and hill dwarves get a bonus to their wisdom.

Aasimar (*Volo's* pages 104-105) get resistance to necrotic damage and protector assimars get a bonus to wisdom.

Dragonborn (PHB pages 32-33) get resistance to one damage type which for green ones is poison damage. They do however not get bonuses to their wisdom.

Warforged (E:RftLW page 36) from Eberron get resistance to poison damage and advantage on saves against poison, and can choose to get a bonus to wisdom. Ask your DM whether Eberron content is right for you.

Yuan-Ti (*Volo's* page 120) get immunity to poison damage, but no bonus to their wisdom and as a monstrous adventurer you will especially need to talk with your DM about availability and what place the race has in that world.

## Low level spells

In part mentioned because it is not available to magic initiate as [*protection from poison*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/protection-from-poison) is a 2nd level spell. It is however a spell on the cleric list which grants resistance to poison damage and advantage on saves against the poisoned condition, in addition to neutralising an extant poisons.

Comment: As a bonus, if you were set on playing a halfling, an Aasimar can be a celestial/just-about-anything crossbreed. So halfling is on, as is everything else.

Comment: @Someone_Evil The tiefling subcare Fierna Tiefling from Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes gets +1 wisdom

Answer (score 7):

## For that combination, play a Hill Dwarf

Your specifications include:

> Are there any other ways to gain *resistance to at least one of these
>   types*? I will likely be a squishy *cleric* in a caster role

1. All dwarves have Dwarven Resilience

   > **Dwarven Resilience**. You have advantage on saving throws against
   >   poison, and you have resistance against poison damage (PHB, Ch 3)
2. Hill Dwarf has +1 Wisdom, +2 Constitution.
   Both will help your cleric.

   > {Dwarf}  Ability Score Increase. Your Constitution score increases by 2.
   >     {Hill Dwarf}  Ability Score Increase. Your Wisdom score increases by 1.
   >   Dwarven Toughness. Your hit point maximum increases by 1, and it increases by 1 every time you gain a level.  (PHB, Ch 3)

   The +1 HP per level is icing on the cake insofar as survivability.

#### Protector Aasimar ... might fulfill your needs

That race grants +1 to wisdom and resistance to necrotic damage, if you want to get resistance to that rather than to poison.  (VGtM, p. 105).  That will also get you a free Light cantrip, some free healing once per day, and a minute of flying once per day.  However, that may not fit your theme as well as the Hill Dwarf.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was hoping to play a halfling, but I'll take it as a maybe.

Comment: @Tiggy Halfling (stout) will work fine, but if you are doing point buy your wisdom will take a while to catch up.  You could also consider taking Water Genasi (+1 Wisdom) and some other neat features, but that's straying from your general plan.